# How can I reorder a certificate chain with shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, openssl

I have a .p7s file with a certificate chain, however, the certificate order is wrong. How, with shell script and possibly openssl, can I rearrange them to the right order (as explained [here](http://blog.edgecloud.com/post/19519955133/ssl-certificate-chain-order-matters))?

Comment: I didn't find any way to do this, I implemented it myself on PHP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a script that reads a chain file (from file or from server), decodes all the certs in the chain, and puts the certificate subjects in the correct order in a tree structure. It can handle forked chains, self-signed certs and multiple separate chains mixed up in one file. Perhaps it could be useful as an example.

https://github.com/onnozweers/TLS-scripts/blob/master/get-certificate-chain